# filtering pandas dataframe when data contains two parts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and want to filter down to all the rows that contain a certain criteria in the “Title” column.
The rows I want to filter down to are all rows that contain the format “(Axx)” (Where xx are 2 numbers).
The data in the “Title” column doesn’t just consist of “(Axx)” data.
The data in the “Title” column looks like so:

```
“some_string (Axx)”
```

What Ive been playing around a bit with different methods but cant seem to get it.
I think the closest ive gotten is:

```
df.filter(regex=r'(D\d{2})', axis=0))
```

but its not correct as the entries aren’t being filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with escape `()` and `$` for end of string and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title':['(D89)','aaa (D71)','(D5)','(D78) aa','D72']})
print (df)
       Title
0      (D89)
1  aaa (D71)
2       (D5)
3   (D78) aa
    
df1 = df[df['Title'].str.contains(r'\(D\d{2}\)$')]
print (df1)
4        D72
       Title
0      (D89)
1  aaa (D71)
```

If ned match only `(Dxx)` use [`Series.str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html):

```
df2 = df[df['Title'].str.match(r'\(D\d{2}\)$')]
print (df2)
   Title
0  (D89)
```